# Can't connect Samsung Note 3 to Windows 7

Tags: usb, windows, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am having problems connecting my Samsung Note 3 to Windows 7 64bit on my laptop. I have installed Kies and drivers already and still nothing. Under device manager it is still labeled "Unknown Device". When I plug in my Note 3 in it will attempt to install device driver but ends up saying "Device unplugged".

I tried both of my USB port on laptop and none of them works. However when I plugged it my desktop it work straight away. Also the weird thing its that the first time when I plugged my Note 3 into my laptop it actually worked for a while. I could access the files in my phone but all of a sudden it just stopped.

Any someone give some advice?

Answer (score 2):

What i would try the following:

**Remember to try to connect to the laptop between each stage and if it still doesnt connect, go to the next step.**

**Doublecheck that your phone can connect to another computer, since my list assumes that the problem is on the pc, and not any settings on the phone.**

1. Use a short usb cable without extenders, and use the best usb port to make sure that your phone gets enough power and speed for the connection. If you have a blue usb port(USB3.0) in your laptop, use that one And use the stock usb to micro usb 3.0 cable.
2. Make sure your phone is up to date by going into "Settings"-> "General"-> "About device"-> "Software update" -> "Update"
3. In early stages of new samsung updates, you need to do it via Kies. Check for an update via your other PC(desktop). Open Kies -> "Tools" -> "Firmware upgrade and initiation"
4. Reinstall Kies and make sure Kies is up to date(under "help"->"check for update")
5. Reinstall the USB driver. Open Kies -> "Tools" -> "Troubleshoot connection error"
6. Reinstall the USB driver manually. http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows