# Unable to connect Galaxy Note3 N9005 to windows 8

Tags: usb, usb-drivers, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I'm having trouble connecting my N9005 to my pc using Windows8. The problem is it does not recognize the phone's storage and is not able to mount it.
I've tried installing Samsung Universal USB Drivers to no avail.
My laptop only has USB2 ports and if I'm correct N9005 utilizes USB v3. Could it be the cause?

I also have the same problem in Ubuntu.

**UPDATE:** I also tried Samsung Kies and it doesn't work either.

**UPDATE 2:** Upon connection my PC recognizes that the phone's been connected but it's not able to mount the storage.

Comment: USB 2.0 supports USB 3.0 no issues there

Comment: You can try the answers suggested here http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64751/note-3-cannot-connect-to-windows-7/64752#64752

Comment: None of them seems to work.

Comment: You can try my steps, might work: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65062/cant-connect-samsung-note-3-to-windows-7/66943#66943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My N9005 was unable to connect via ADB on Windows 8. etc, and I fixed it by entering the `*#0808#` dialer code on the caller screen to change the USB connection mode.

You will see the mode about ADB at the bottom. I tried it and it worked for me, but only for the ADB connection. I did not try other options. Look for MTP options, and also find the USB driver for Windows in any case.

[image]
<sup>Click image for full size</sup>

Comment: Worked for me, it seemed the phone did not need a restart. You can go through each option with Kies 3 open and it will detect it suddenly when you get the right option AP - MTP + ADB worked for me.